# GetData from server Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have next function:

```
private void getAllData()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://webservice.com/wfwe");
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), request);
    }
        void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
        using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            GetApplications(result);
        }
    }
```

And i fill in stack panels:

```
private void GetApplications(string result)
    {
        var ApplicationsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Applications>>(result);
        foreach (Applications A in ApplicationsList)
        {
            foreach (ApplicationRelation SCA in A.ApplicationRelations)
            {
                if (SCA.ApplicationSubcategory != null)
                {
                    #region Fill Customer Research Stack
                    if (SCA.ApplicationSubcategory.subcategoryName == "Customer Research")
                    {
                        if (TestStack.Children.Count == 0)
                        {
                            ApplicationTile AT = FillDataForApplicationTile(SCA);                                
                            AT.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 0);
                            TestStack.Children.Add(AT);
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And code fails at:

if (TestStack.Children.Count == 0)

**Error: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))**

**How can i rewrite my Request from void to string, so i could do something like this:**

```
GetApplications(await getAllData())
```

**EDIT 2 for dcastro:**

[image]

**EDIT 3:**

Thanks it works, but i was looking for something like this:

//Modified your code:

```
GetApplications(getAllData2().Result);

private async Task<string> getAllData2()
    {
       string uri = "http://webservice.com/wfe";
       var client = new HttpClient();
       HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
       var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       return result.ToString();
    }
```

But somehow my construction doesn't enter GetApplication function...

Comment: Can you show us the piece of code calling `getAllData`?

Comment: I don't think changing your method to work like `GetApplications(await getAllData())` would fix the problem. I think you're trying to access `TestStack`, which is an UI element, from a non-UI thread. If you could post a little more code, I may be able to help out more.

Comment: In your current approach (Edit 3), `.Result` is causing a deadlock. Read this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
private async Task<string> getAllData()
{
    string Result = "";
    var http = new HttpClient();
    var response = await http.GetAsync("http://webservice.com/wfwe"); // I am considering this URL gives me JSON
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // You will get JSON here
    }
    else
    {
        Result = response.StatusCode.ToString(); // Error while accesing the web service.
    }

    return Result;
}

private async Task GetApplications(string result)
{
    var ApplicationsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Applications>>(result);
    foreach (Applications A in ApplicationsList)
    {
        foreach (ApplicationRelation SCA in A.ApplicationRelations)
        {
            if (SCA.ApplicationSubcategory != null)
            {
                #region Fill Customer Research Stack
                if (SCA.ApplicationSubcategory.subcategoryName == "Customer Research")
                {
                    if (TestStack.Children.Count == 0)
                    {
                        // This will update your UI using UI thread
                        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                        {
                            ApplicationTile AT = FillDataForApplicationTile(SCA);
                            AT.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 0);
                            TestStack.Children.Add(AT);
                        });
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest, how can i rewrite my original:

private void getAllData()
void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)

into 1 function, so that i can use them like this:

string a = new Function ();  // made out of two above

Comment: `getAllData()` & `GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)` is already merged. You can now call `await GetApplications(await getAllData())`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `AsyncCallback` (which I'm pretty sure is running `GetResponsetStreamCallback` in a non-UI thread), try fetching your data like this:

```
private async void getAllData()
   string uri = "http://webservice.com/wfwe";
   var client = new HttpClient();

   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

   string body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

   GetApplications(body);
}
```

This will call your webservice asynchronously (at line `await Client.sendMessageAsync(msg);`), and return to the original UI thread when the response is received. This way, you can update UI elements, like your `TestStack`.

**Edit** fixed bug

Comment: Error 4 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'sendMessageAsync' and no extension method 'sendMessageAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Added screenshot for you in my question

Comment: In your current approach `.Result` is causing a deadlock. Read this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html